# Azure SQL authentication through AD service principal

Tags: c#, azure, adal, azure-ad-msal

I am having a windows client application connecting directly to a SQL server.
I am using SQL server authentication now, but I want to replace that for improved security. (I don't want to deploy the credentials together with the application)

I want to use Azure AD to provide access to the app (and forwarding the access token to the DB)

My desired setup would look like:
I have a Azure AD app registration (service principal).
- I assign permission to use the application individually --> Enterprise App --> User assignment required --> Yes
- I give permission to the app (service principal) on the SQL database.
- What I can do now is to access the DB as the logged in user (API permission Azure SQL Server --> user_impersonation), but that means, that I have to give access to all individual users directly on the DB.
I would like to access the DB as the application.

Is this possible, and if yes, how?

Now, I am able to use ADAL to connect as the service principal to the DB, but then I have to create a client secret for the service principal and deploy that together with the application --> not secure. Or I can use MSAL with user_delegation and access the DB as the logged-in user but that means that I have to give him direct access to the DB and he can access it in another way as just with the application (i.e. in MSSMS).

Comment: A way of doing that might be to encrypt a file and have your application decrypt it. That way no one with acess to the deployment server can actually read the application secret.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like what you want to use is a managed identity.

There's a tutorial here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-connect-msi

I should warn you this managed identity feature is new-ish and you need to be careful what version of .Net framework your application is using. Some Azure App Service and other ressources are not yet updated to a .Net framework that supports managed identities (Last I know).